# Rails new path. So i have transfer_path, like edit_path works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi have a Rails app and users here can edit patients.

I'm trying to use same/similar link to use the same edit form, but it will be for patient transfer. So I new a new path. So do I create a transfer_patient_path, like edit_patient_path?

Here is my controller

I need to get "transfers", working like edit.

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_patient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_login

  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @patients = Patient.search(params[:query])
    else
      @patients = Patient.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
    end
    #@patients = current_user.patients.order(:id)
  end

  def show
    #@patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @patient = current_user.patients.build
  end

  def create
    @patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params)

    if @patient.save
      redirect_to patient_path(@patient), notice: "Patient Added"
    else
      @errors = @patient.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:id])
  end

   def transfer
      @patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:id])
   end

  def update
    @patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:id])

    if @patient.update_attributes(patient_params)
      redirect_to patient_path(@patient), notice: "Patient Update"
    else
      @errors = @patient.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end



  def destroy
    patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:id])
    patient.destroy
    redirect_to  patients_path, notice: "Delete Patient #{patient.name}"
  end

  def report 
          render 'patients/report'
  end

  private
    def patient_params
      params.require(:patient).permit(:name, :age, :phone, :ailment, :apointment, :status)
    end

    def find_patient
      @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

This is the patient show page where edit is accessed from, and ideally so would transfers.

Transfers will be a copy of the edit field, just with the ability to change one additional field.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table show-table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Ailment</th>
                    <th>Apointment</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Hospital</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= @patient.name %></td>
                        <td><%= @patient.age %></td>
                        <td><%= @patient.phone %></td>
                        <td><%= @patient.ailment %></td>
                        <td><%= @patient.apointment %></td>
                        <td><%= @patient.status %></td>
                        <td>Hospital</td>
                        <td><td><%= link_to "Transfer", transfer_patient_path(@patient)%></td></td>
                        <td><%= link_to "Back", patients_path %></td>
                        <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_patient_path(@patient)%></td>
                        <td><%= link_to( "Delete", patient_path(@patient), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete: #{@patient.name}?"},method: :delete) %></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="text-lead text-center mt-3 mb-2">Previous Visit Reports</h3>
            <div class="report-table" align="center">
                <% if @patient.reports.count ==0 %>
                    <center><h1>This patient has no medical reports on file</h1></center>
                <% else %>
                <table class="table table table-bordered table-striped show-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th/>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% @patient.reports.each do |report|%>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= report.date %></td>
                                <td><%= report.title %></td>
                                <td><%= link_to "View Report", patient_report_path(report.patient.id,report.id),class: "button_one" %></td>
                                <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_patient_report_path(report.patient.id,report.id),class: "button_one" %></td>
                                <td><%= link_to "Delete", patient_report_path(report.patient.id,report.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"},class: "button_one" %></td>
                            </tr>
                        <% end %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <% end %>
            <% if signed_in? %>
                <%= link_to "Add Visit Report", new_patient_report_path(@patient),class: "button_one" %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get this working, you'll need to set up a route beyond the standard restful that rails provides out of the box. I imagine your routes for patients looks something like this right now:

```
resources :patients
```

or maybe

```
resources :patients, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

You'll want to add your `transfer` route to this as well:

```
resources :patients, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  collection do
    get 'transfer'
  end
end
```

This will give you a `transfer_patient_url` and `transfer_patient_path` that you can use like the edit path. For more information on routing like this, check out the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Then all you'll need to do is modify your controller to have to have a `transfer` action. You'll probably want to modify your `before_action` to include `transfer` as well.

Comment: Alternatively you can leave out the `collection` block and use `get 'transfer', on: :collection`. It's also good to keep in mind that if you're working with permissions you might want to set a hidden field with the action the user is performing. For example if a user has permissions to edit a patient, but doesn't have permissions to transfer a patient. This way you can check the permissions of a user in the update method based on the action he/she is performing before actually updating the resource.